# Error Message: Can't determine a valid Java Home

Tags: java

I think my path is not set correctly for some reason.

"Path" under System Variables looks following:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\

Under User Variable Path or Java_home is not there?

***Is there a way to start the path over again?***

Comment: post some code otherwise you will get slammed :)

Comment: If JAVA_HOME is not there then add it as a user variable. And explain what you are trying to do and what you mean by "click to edit". Code is most likely not needed here.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do a few things:

- define a new variable `JAVA_HOME` and assign to it exactly ***JDK*** installation location, like `C:\java\jdk_1.8.0`
- update your `Path` variable with:

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin

- important point ***set it first*** to `Path`.
  Finally, your `Path` will look:

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows

- open console and type:

> java -version

The output should be something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

BTW your `Path` has some duplication. Just remove an unneeded part.